# Implementing multiple position dodges

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In ggplot2 I would like to have control over multiple position dodges within variables and factors in a barplot or crossbar plot. For example:

```
data = data.frame(Var=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                Val=c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.0,0.1),
                g1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                g2=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                g3=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))

q = ggplot(data,aes(Var,Val,ymin = Val-0.15,
                    ymax=Val+0.15,
                    group=g1,
                    colour=factor(g2),
                    fill=factor(g2),
                    linetype=factor(g3),))
q + geom_crossbar(width=0.5,fatten=2,size=0.5,position=position_dodge(width=0.51)) + 
    coord_flip() +  
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00000090","#00000090","#00000050","#00000050")) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("#000000","#00000070","#000000","#00000070"))
```

In the example above, I would like to be able to slightly separate the darker bars from the lighter bars, while keeping each bar set together. Can I implement multiple position dodges in order to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I propose using `facet_grid` to simulate the nested dodging that you want. To do that, I created a new factor `g4` that groups the light gray and dark gray bars.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(Var=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                Val=c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.0,0.1),
                g1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                g2=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                g3=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))

dat$g4 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2) # New grouping factor

fill_values   = c("#00000090","#00000090","#00000050","#00000050")
colour_values = c("#000000","#00000070","#000000","#00000070")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fig1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=Var, y=Val, ymin=Val - 0.15, ymax=Val + 0.15, 
              colour=factor(g2), fill=factor(g2), linetype=factor(g3))) +
    geom_crossbar(width=0.5, fatten=2, size=0.5,
                  position=position_dodge(width=0.51)) +
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=fill_values) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=colour_values) +
    opts(title="Figure 1: Original Version")

png("fig1.png", height=600, width=600)
print(fig1)
dev.off()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fig2 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(g4), y=Val, ymin=Val - 0.15,ymax=Val + 0.15, 
              colour=factor(g2), fill=factor(g2), linetype=factor(g3))) +
    geom_crossbar(width=0.7, fatten=2, size=0.5,
                  position=position_dodge()) +
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=fill_values) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=colour_values) +
    facet_grid(Var ~ .) +
    opts(title="Figure 2: Proposed Solution")

png("fig2.png", height=600, width=600)
print(fig2)
dev.off()
```

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 3):

**Updated code** and plot

Here's an approach that separates the light grey from the dark grey in the one panel. It involves subsetting the data so that in two calls to `geom_crossbar`, the light grey corssbars are positioned in the first call, then the dark grey crossbars are positionned in the second call. I've added another grouping variable to the data frame to allow the subsetting of the data.

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(Var=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                Val=c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.0,0.1),
                g1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                g2=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                g3=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))
data$g4 = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)

q = ggplot(data, aes(Var,Val,ymin = Val-0.15,
    ymax=Val+0.15, group=g1, colour=factor(g2),
    fill=factor(g2), linetype=factor(g3)))

# Position the light grey crossbars
q = q + geom_crossbar(data = subset(data, data$g4 == 1), 
        aes(as.numeric(Var) - .12, Val, ymin = Val-0.15, ymax = Val + 0.15), 
        width = 0.2, fatten = 1.25, size = 0.65, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))

library(grid)
# position the dark grey crossbars, and tidy up
q + geom_crossbar(data = subset(data, data$g4 == 2), 
        aes(as.numeric(Var) + .12, Val, ymin = Val-0.15, ymax = Val + 0.15), 
        width = 0.2, fatten = 1.25, size = 0.65, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2), labels = c("a", "b"), expand = c(.2, 0)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00000057", "#00000057", "#00000020", "#00000020")) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#000000", "#00000070", "#000000", "#00000070")) +
    coord_flip() +  theme_bw() +
   theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: @bdemarest and Sandy, both of these approaches are great, and useful in different situations. Thanks so much!